# .play() is not working, the animation does not happen. Any fixes?

Tags: javascript, animation

I tried doing `hoverSprite.play("walk)` but it did not work, it just output an error: `hoverSprite.play()` is not defined.

```js
this.anims.create({
  key: "walk",
  frameRate: 4,
  repeat: -1,
  frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("cat", {
    frames: [0, 1, 2, 3]
  })
});

playButton.setInteractive();

playButton.on("pointerover", () => {
  hoverSprite.setVisible(true);
  hoverSprite.play("walk");
  hoverSprite.x = playButton.x - playButton.width;
  hoverSprite.y = playButton.y;
})
```

Comment: We're going to need a *much* more complete example with all relevant code if you're expecting anyone to be able to debug this.

Comment: Also, I'm going to assume you're using a framework for the animations? That should really be tagged in the question to save people having to guess or assume at what methods you're trying to invoke.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.